# Ordered Randomness

Tags: mysql, sql, random

Can someone please help me with this query?

Questions:

- ID - Autonum
- Question - Memo
- Category - Integer(1-5)

Answers:

- ID - Autonum
- FID - Integer
- Answer - Memo

One question, many possible answers

I need a query that will show all questions from category#1 in random order. After each question, it will show it's possible answers also in random order. Then it will do it for category#2 and so on.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT Questions.ID, Questions.Question, Questions.Category, Answers.Answer
FROM Questions INNER JOIN Answers ON Questions.ID = Answers.FID
ORDER BY Questions.Category, RND(Questions.ID);
```

It correctly keeps all the categories together but the rest is random. I'm not sure how to keep the Questions.ID's together (but in a random order) while making the answers order random also.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I think a subquery might help:

```
SELECT q.ID, q.Question, q.Category, a.Answer
FROM (SELECT q.*, rand() as rnd FROM Questions q) q INNER JOIN
     Answers a
     ON q.ID = a.FID
ORDER BY q.Category, q.rnd, rand();
```

Comment: Damn you're fast! :-)

Comment: TYVM for the quick response!

I modified the "rand()" to "RND()" and the "rnd" to "rand", for MSAccess.  It runs, but the Questions.ID isn't grouped together.

Comment: @user2182715 . . . Your question is tagged "mysql", not "ms-access".